# How do I find f(x) (Z→R) that satisfy f(x) +f(y) +f (xy+1) =f(x+y) +f(1) +f(xy)?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I am looking for all functions f(x) (Z→R)
that satisfy
f(x) +f(y) +f (xy+1) =f(x+y) +f(1) +f(xy)?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).